# AngularJS: How to create a directive that adds/removes itself from DOM when needed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

If i have a custom modal directive that looks something like this:

```
return {
  restirct: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'modal.html',
  scope: {
    modalContent: "=",
    modalOpen: "="
  }
}
```

and the html:

```
<ng-modal modal-content="content" modal-open"active"></ng-modal>
```

how can i make sure that the modal doesn't exist in the DOM when it's closed and once open it inserts itself into the DOM? I have to insert the directive into the html or else the directive won't work but that means that when i run the application the modal already exists in the html even if it wasn't opened.

I created a plunker of what i have so far [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kqkVOM6sahbWJo6EmrMO?p=preview) but it only hides/shows the modal using css classes instead of removing it completely

### EDIT:

I created another version [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEPYVhzBHgGE0itEFoXW?p=preview) which actually adds/removes the directive from the DOM. It's based on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1038684/AngularJs-Add-Remove-Directives-Dynamically-Save-D) article but it requires splitting the logic for adding/removing the directive between the directive and an external controller (The external controller handles adding the element and the directive handles the removing). I want the directive to handle everything, is this possible?

Comment: I once created very simple modal service (note: not directive) with API similar to BootstrapUI $modal service. Check it (out)[https://github.com/dfsq/angular-google-tasks/blob/master/app/components/services/sModal.service.js]. It creates and removes modal properly.

Comment: Why not use the `ng-if` directive? The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @georgeawg this only works if i put the ng-if on the content inside the template, if i put the ng-if on the `<ng-modal>` directive then the directive won't work at all. Also i would like to have the ability to control where the directive is inserted/appended which isn't possible with ng-if.

Comment: What work have you done to solve the problem? And what difficulty have you had so far?

Comment: @georgeawg edited original question with what i have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want? I wrapped the contents of your template with a single div so that it was easier to grab the whole chunk in one variable. Then I add and remove that div depending on whether you want to show or hide it.

I do not believe that you can remove the `<ng-modal>` element, but this at least removes everything inside of it...

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lr77FuGwcPbojgf3fHuW?p=preview

**html**

```
<div>
  <div class="modal hide">
    <h4>{{modalContent.title}}</h4>
    <p>{{modalContent.text}}</p>
    <button ng-click="close()">Close Modal</button>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var ModalDirective = function() {
  return {
    restirct: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    scope: {
      modalContent: "=",
      modalOpen: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var modalElements = element.children()[0];
      console.log(element);

      function addModal() {
        console.log('Opening modal');
        element.addClass('open');
        //add the modal elements back into the directive
        if (modalElements) {
          //should be 0
          console.log('Element child count before add', element.children().length);
          element[0].appendChild(modalElements);
           //should be 1
           console.log('Element child count after add', element.children().length);
        }
      }

      function removeModal() {
        element.removeClass('open');
        console.log('Closing modal');
        if (modalElements) {
          //remove the modal elements from the directive
           //should be 1
          console.log('Element child count before remove', element.children().length);
          element[0].removeChild(modalElements);
          //should be 0
          console.log('Element child count after remove', element.children().length);
        }
      }

      scope.$watch('modalOpen', function(newVal, oldVal) {

        if (newVal) {
          addModal();
        } else {
          removeModal();
        }

      });

      scope.close = function() {
        scope.modalOpen = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion that it doesn't seem to be possible to remove the ng-modal tag without relying on an external controller. The solution i ended up with is similar to your approach except i use the $templateCache service to store the html for the `modalElements` instead of relying on it already existing.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery :

```
$(element).remove()
```

With no jquery :

```
element.html("")
element.remove();
element.empty();
```